# What is the term for a three dimensional region of space - as we have "surface" and "curve" for lower dimensions?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, terminology, volume

What is the term for a three dimensional region of space - as we have *surface* and *curve* for two and one dimensions respectively?

I've sometimes seen this called a *volume*, although I find that misleading, as volume is typically a measure (a real number) on such a region.

Likewise for higher dimensions.

Comment: The only common name I can think of is "manifold". For example, you say "a three-dimensional manifold" to refer to a region in $\mathbb{R}^4$ parametrized by three parameters (degrees of freedom), etc.

Comment: You can say "solid" or "solid figure".

Comment: For dimension 3, the common terms are 3-space or 3-manifold. Similarly, in dimension $n$, it’s $n$-space or $n$-manifold.

Answer (score 2):

As someone answered you in comments, as far as I know, there is no specific terminology like in lower dimensions. However, one often refers to a manifold of dimension $3$ as 3-manifold or, in a fancier way, as threefold or $3$-fold.

Comment: Agreed. Just wanted to say that I've seen "threefold" or "3-fold" mostly in algebraic geometry.